# Graph API unauthorized error

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I thought that there are some data on graph api which we can explore
without access tokens.
but now following code returns me unauthorized.m puzzled why??
My code as follows:

```
FacebookAPI fb = new FacebookAPI();
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("message", "hello");
JSONObject object1 = fb.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of authorization token, whether a user token, or an app token. Just use your app token, which makes it simple:

```
var fbClient = new FacebookClient(appAccessToken);
var res = fbClient.Get("4"); // mark zuckerberg
```